.clangd file add multiple CompileFlags
I am currently trying to setup a .clangd file to use for my lsp ...
how can i add multiple compile flags?
my file is autogenerated and looks like this:
CompileFlags:
Add:
    - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include
    - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\lua
    - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\raylib
    - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\rlimgui
    - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\rlimgui\extras
    - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src
    - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\asseteditor
    - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\textureeditor
    - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\ui
    - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\utils

I also tried it this way:
CompileFlags:
Add: [-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include,-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\lua,-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\raylib,-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\rlimgui,-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\rlimgui\extras,-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src,-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\asseteditor,-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\textureeditor,-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\ui,-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\utils]

If i do:
CompileFlags:
    Add: -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\raylib

Or:
CompileFlags:
    Add: 
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\raylib

it works just fine for one include path but as soon as i add another one it doesnt load anymore.
Is there another solution to this?

I fixed it by creating a compile_flags.txt in the source directory which has following content:
-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include
-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\lua
-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\raylib
-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\rlimgui
-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\rlimgui\extras
-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src
-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\asseteditor
-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\textureeditor
-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\ui
-IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\utils

simple as that i can use my lsp without problems with clangd
for anyone having the same issue i automated the creation of the file with a simple python file:
import os

dir_path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

include_paths = []

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(f"{dir_path}\\include"):
    if path not in include_paths:
        include_paths.append(path)
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(f"{dir_path}\\src"):
    if path not in include_paths:
        include_paths.append(path)

with open("compile_flags.txt", mode="w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
    for path in include_paths:
        file.write(f'-I{path}\n')

just run it in source dir, you can edit the folder paths "include" and "source" by your needs

It's important for Add: to be indented relative to CompileFlags:.
Either of your first two examples should work with that change, for example:
CompileFlags:
    Add:
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\lua
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\raylib
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\rlimgui
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\include\rlimgui\extras
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\asseteditor
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\textureeditor
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\ui
        - -IC:\Users\adria\Desktop\Nimble_New\src\utils

(If that still does not work, please post clangd logs for further diagnosis.)

I indented it in my file. It just didnt indent when I copied it

@BigAgg Ok. I see you've found a workaround, but if you're still interested in finding out why the original approach doesn't work, please feel free to share logs as mentioned.

I will after this weekend. Got plenty to do for now but i will come back to this for sure thanks for pointing out the logging
